# Graph API issue while Instagram Video Posting - Media upload has failed with error code 2207026"

Tags: facebook-graph-api, format, error-code, instagram-graph-api, video-upload

My program is working perfectly fine when I try to upload Pictures through graph API on Instagram.
But when I try to upload videos through graph API it gives this error

```
    {"id":"17907424258891270","status":"Error: Media upload has failed with error code 2207026","status_code":"ERROR"}
Loop Continue y/n-> n
{"error":{"message":"The video file you selected is in a format that we don't support.","type":"OAuthException","code":352,"error_subcode":2207026,"is_transient":false,"error_user_title":"Unsupported format","error_user_msg":"The video format is not supported. Please check spec for supported streams format","fbtrace_id":"AfZ_9eCYSY3iJ6g0QRX0bM-"}}
```

I have tried different video formats. Tried videos with different codecs too. Have also tried publicly accessible videos and local videos too but I am having the same error
Here is my code

```
def uploadToInstagram(ig_user_id,access_token,video_url,caption=""):
    url1 = "https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/"+str(ig_user_id)+ "/media?caption=" +caption+"&video_url="+ video_url+ "&media_type=VIDEO&access_token="+ access_token
    r = requests.post(url1)
    print(r.text)
creation_id = json.loads(r.text)['id'] 
print(creation_id)

while True:    
    x = input("Loop Continue y/n-> ")
    if x == "n":
        break    
    else:
        pass
    url3 = "https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/" +creation_id+"?fields=id,status,status_code&access_token="+ access_token
    status_check = requests.get(url3)
    print(status_check.text)
    #status_code = json.loads(status_check.text)["status_code"]

url2  = "https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/" +str(ig_user_id)+"/media_publish?creation_id="+ creation_id+"&access_token="+access_token 
r = requests.post(url2)
print(r.text)

if __name__ == "__main__":

#video_path = "https://pixabay.com/videos/download/video-4006_large.mp4?attachment" 

#Check this one v
video_path ='https://player.vimeo.com/external/176282263.hd.mp4?s=5ae9c441e89ee36646286c22fddc6c8781946c7d&profile_id=169'
#video_path ="1000_general_Fall.mp4"
video_path="https://vod-progressive.akamaized.net/exp=1625867691~acl=%2Fvimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us%2F01%2F256%2F7%2F176282263%2F572345167.mp4~hmac=e4378a5d76e659bd11289e1b3dcfe7bb95eaf0b20de9cbb22c9b5ed1b418100d/vimeo-prod-skyfire-std-us/01/256/7/176282263/572345167.mp4?filename=Sea+-+4006.mp4"
enter code here
```

Comment: I am having same issue right now, did you solve it?

Comment: Same for me, I can't publish mp4 videos that seem to fit the specs!

Comment: I have downloaded it from Insta video and can't post it with the same error ))